# How can I have a temporary variable declared in a MERGE statement in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to use a temporary variable declared in stored procedure. I need to use this variable to assign a value and do some function in a Matched statement. How can I use? is there any other way to have value??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can define a local variable in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @MyVariable INT
SET @MyVariable = 12
SELECT HouseNumber + @MyVariable as NewHouseNumber FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable preceding the `MERGE` statement then you can indeed use that variable within the `MERGE` statement. This apples to table variables as well as scalar variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think he ment something like this

```
MERGE TargetTable as tar
USING SourceTable as src
ON tar.SomeID = src.OtherID

DECLARE @BossId INT
SET @BossId = (SELECT ID FROM EmployeeTable WHERE [BossID] = src.BossID)
--Here we take dynamicly an ID from another table

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (list OF fields, [BossID])
  VALUES (list OF values, @BossId)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET (list OF SET statements);
```

This way in every INSERT statement will have different BossID. Is this even possible? If not - How to insert records this way? Imagine that the SourceTable (which in my case is an input parameter in a SP) came with ID which needs to be mapped with another talbe. Any suggestions?

My post is more like an addition to the original question.